# How do I reinstall the "HID Compliant Driver"?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, controller

**System Specifications:**
Operating System: Windows 7, Home Premium 64-bit Service Pack 1
Problem: Driver-related

**Problem:**
I have a wired Afterglow Gamepad Controller for XBox 360 and there seem to be no drivers for the device at all! Upon checking Device Manager, I received an Error 28 (which is what I just stated above).
I tried googling and searching for drivers on my system/the device itself and there seem to be no driver. I've tried installing the generic drivers (found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-gb/d/xbox-360-controller-for-windows) <sub>[microsoft.com]</sub>) and they (of course) do not work.

Another thing I've also found is that I'm missing a HID Compliant Driver (as it's so called), and of course: It can't be found anywhere through googling as it's usually a different driver for each type of device (ie. Mouse, Keyboard, Game Controller etc.).

**Question:** How do I install the "HID Compliant Driver" so that Windows can detect my device?
*From what I've found out so far of the problem, it seems like the device proper driver is find/usable, it's just that the complementary driver ('HID Compliant Controller' driver or whatever it's called) is missing as the same problem is happening with my Wiimote (except over Bluetooth).*

**Edit 1:** If you haven't already figured out, I'm trying to use my xbox controller on my PC.
**Edit 2:** The drivers were working last year, until I reformatted my laptop (clean wipe of everything).
**Edit 3:** I've been experimenting with all sorts of drivers (and the 'no driver at all'), but the thing I seem to always notice happening is that when I insert the controller, the lights blink (on the controller) and Windows plays two low-pitched sounds, instead of a low pitched followed by a high pitched note (which means a device has been plugged in and is ready to use). Yes, I've tried it in nearly all ports.
**Edit 4:** It's not in Device Manager, the driver simply does not exist on my system at all!

Comment: Controllers are often notoriously difficult to connect to your PC. However, it usually is possible in most cases. One large problem is that Microsoft removed the drivers from their site years ago.

Comment: This sounds like a system corruption problem

Comment: Anywhere to get the drivers or did they discontinue support?

Comment: You won't be able to get this device to work until you solve your inability to install the `HID Compliant Driver` which is the sole reason the device is not showing up, hence my original comment, you have a corrupt system image because the HID Compliant Driver should already exist by default.

Comment: So, how would I go about trying to reinstall the HID Compliant Driver? Because it's not on my system.

Comment: How does the device show up in the Device Manager and does it have a yellow mark? Have you tried to update the driver while specifying from your computer? Or to delete the device and reboot while it's connected.

Comment: It doesn't show up in Device Manager at all @harrymc

Comment: Do you get any dialog or traybar balloon when you connect it to USB? Does something new appear then in Device Manager in the "Human Interface Devices" section (it might be even better to post a screenshot of it)? Do you have any problems with other devices on same USB port and have you tried other ports?

Comment: Nope. It just made two low-pitched notes when I plugged it in. No tray balloons and removal just resulted in the per-normal events; a high-pitched note followed by a low pitched one.

Comment: Doesn't seem to appear at all - http://gyazo.com/780999852450a31eedd4bfb08c552712 | Those installed doesn't work as it's the wrong device.

Comment: Try to install [this driver](http://www.driverscape.com/download/afterglow-gamepad-for-xbox-360) and reboot with the device connected. If this works you will find in Device Manager "AfterGlow Gamepad for XBox 360". If not, try to search all other branches in Device Manager for a device named "Unknown Device" or having its icon overlayed with a yellow exclamation mark.

Comment: It is an installer for a piece of software called "Driver Toolkit" and it does nothing without me having to "register" (pay money for) it... It's not a driver at all! | Linked to: http://www.driverscape.com/files/driver_setup.exe

Comment: Sorry about that - I was misled. Do you see anything suspicious anywhere in Device Manager?

Comment: Apart from drivers not present, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely, your system somehow "misplaced" its C:\Windows\System32\drivers\*hid*.sys files.  A normally functioning system can be expected to have the following files:

- hidclass.sys
- hidparse.sys
- hidusb.sys
- kbdhid.sys
- hidbth.sys
- hidir.sys
- mouhid.sys
- hidbatt.sys
- VMBusHID.sys

There are two options for restoring any of these missing files.

- Copy the file from C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository (they will be in sub-directories under this structure)
- Expand the file from your windows 7 dvd

  - Open D:\sources\install.wim with a utility like 7-zip
  - Browse to the drivers folder (\1\Windows\System32\drivers)
  - Extract the driver files you need

**Note** You may need to get the inf files as well.  In that case follow the instructions on [this article](https://forum.raymond.cc/threads/how-to-extract-drivers-from-vista-dvd-for-windows-7.15176/).

Likely, all you are missing is **hidusb.sys** but I would check for all of them.  This should address your missing HID driver issue.  As to the gamepad itself, I would highly recommend uninstalling its drivers before attempting this fix, then re-installing.

Comment: From Windows Vista onwards, there is **no `i386` folder**. Instead the OP would have to copy over the `install.wim` file (around 3-4GB uncompressed), and navigate to the `Windows/System32` folder in there.

Comment: You're absolutely right, goes to show how long it's been since I've dealt with this type of issue.  I will amend my answer to reflect the correct approach.